# Register command cli locally through npm

Tags: npm, command-line-interface

I have the following case, where we need to install cypress CLI in order to use it easily through commands. However on our build machines we don't wish to install the CLI as there's already a path to the CLI installed locally in `"./node_modules/.bin/cypress"`.

So we have created a command in `package.json` - `"cypress":"./node_modules/.bin/cypress"`, and run commands with ... npm run cypress ... and everything works fine.

Is there a way we can register "cypress" as a command in the local repo without the need of the CLI, so whenever you run cypress in bash - it doesn't yell "bash: cypress: command not found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [`npx`](https://github.com/npm/npx) and let it figure out the local path for cypress if you wish to execute it directly

for instance,

```
$ npm install --save-dev cypress

$ npx cypress --version
Cypress package version: 6.0.0
Cypress binary version: 6.0.0
Electron version: 11.0.2
Bundled Node version: 12.18.3
```

if you wrap cypress in a [`run-script`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/using-npm/scripts), then there is no need to call npx. for instance:

```sh
$ cat package.json | jq -r '.scripts.cypress'
cypress

$ npm run cypress -- --version

> goo@1.0.0 cypress /private/tmp/goo
> cypress "--version"

Cypress package version: 6.0.0
Cypress binary version: 6.0.0
Electron version: 11.0.2
Bundled Node version: 12.18.3
```